# Android App to WebServer

Tags: android, web-services, firebase, webserver, firebase-remote-config

I am newbie doing my Master Thesis on Android development.  I already have developed an android app, however the challenging task en route completing my master thesis successfully is to link this android application to a web server.  Here is the actual description of the task

- I provide the user the web server link where my application is hosted.  Once the user gets into the web server
- He would be provided with some feature list which he will select and click on the download link, once all this is done, the source code should compile and install the apk to his/her device based on the feature lists selected.

Can this be done? If so I would really appreciate your help in guiding me in the right direction to achieve this.

Comment: Quick thinking, you can make versions of your app 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 etc depending on feature sets and let users download the corresponding .apk's.

Comment: @Lev thanks. However this is more into a product line development.  The application should be built only after the user selects the feature list.  I can't have different versions of the app.  Just think like, the user wants to select a few features he would wish to pay for, the app should then be built according to his needs.

Comment: in this case, I won't be able to help you :) Good luck.